# How can I Upgrade CS-Cart from 4.9.3.SP1 to 4.10.1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cs-cart

My host is AWS and I need to update my cs-cart from 4.9.3.SP1 to 4.10.1 and I tried to execute the update but get below error for FTP:

> Permissions issue These files require write permissions set (manually
>   or automatically via FTP)

Answer (score 0):

Check right on folder:

```
/restore/
/var/upgrade - and maybe i
```

Answer (score -1):

Some directories do not have write access, please enter the FTP account in the cs-cart settings to configure.